# Find files that match lines of a txt and then cp them to a new directory

Tags: file, unix, while-loop, find, cp

I have a whitelist.txt. Inside this txt is a list of file names simliar to this:

```
9853412_00000_0_0.vcf
7549682_00000_0_0.vcf
3589647_00000_0_0.vcf
```

I want to look inside a specific SOURCE directory for files whose name matches the ones in the whitelist. Then I want to copy the matched files to a new TARGET directory.

For example, if files in my source directory looks like the following:

```
9853412_00000_0_0.vcf
7549682_00000_0_0.vcf
3589647_00000_0_0.vcf
8965423_00000_0_0.vcf
2547936_00000_0_0.vcf
5479241_00000_0_0.vcf
```

Then my script should be able to select the first 3 vcfs from the SOURCE and copy them to the TARGET.

I have tried these scripts. They run without error message, but no files could be cp from SOURCE to TARGET, and I am not sure why.

```
#!/bin/sh

SOURCE="/my/source/dir/*.vcf"
TARGET="/my/target/dir/"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    find $SOURCE -type f -name "$line" -exec cp {} $TARGET \;  
done < whitelist.txt
```

```
#!/bin/sh

SOURCE="/my/source/dir/*.vcf"
TARGET="/my/target/dir/"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    find $SOURCE -type f -name "${line}" -exec cp '{}' $TARGET \;  
done < whitelist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, just remove the `*.vcf`.

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="/my/source/dir/"
TARGET="/my/target/dir/"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    find "$SOURCE" -type f -name "$line" -exec cp {} $TARGET \;
done < whitelist.txt
```